# dropdownlist redirect remember chosen option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a dropdownlist that contains some parameters for the url on the change event. So when you select an option from the list it will redirect you to the same page with some extra parameters to query the data. The problem is when you change dropdownlist it doesn't remember it's selected option could someone show me how to have a dropdowlist show the selected option across url changes.

```
<script tpye="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#sort_by').on('change', function(e) {
            window.location.href + $(this).val();   
        })
    })
</script>

<select id="sort_by" name="sort_by">
    <option>Sort By</option>
    <option value="&sort_by=title&direction=asc">Title ASC</option>
    <option value="&sort_by=title&direction=desc">Title DESC</option>
    <option value="&sort_by=created_date&direction=asc">Created Date ASC</option>
    <option value="&sort_by=created_date&title=asc">Created Date DESC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you want to achieve this at the client side. Since the user is selecting an option. So wouldn't that make this more of a Javascript question?

Comment: This won't select an option which matches URI string automatically. You need a bit logic to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i have added an extra parameter in query string 'chosen' to make the dropdown remember its selected value.

```
$option[0] = array('value'=>'','title'=>'Sort By');  
$option[1] = array('value'=>'?sort_by=title&direction=asc&chosen=1','title'=>'Title ASC');
$option[2] = array('value'=>'?sort_by=title&direction=desc&chosen=2','title'=>'Title DESC');
$option[3] = array('value'=>'?sort_by=created_date&direction=asc&chosen=3','title'=>'Created Date ASC');
$option[4] = array('value'=>'?sort_by=created_date&title=asc&chosen=4','title'=>'Created Date DESC');



<select id="sort_by" name="sort_by">
    <?php foreach($option as $key=>$val){ 
            $a = ""; if($_GET['chosen']==$key){$a = 'selected="selected"';} 
            echo '<option '.$a.' value="'.$val['value'].'">'.$val['title'].'</option>';

 } ?>

</select>
```

Hope it might help.